# Setting up map markers and Info windows using javaScript remoting call

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, google-map

I need to populate a map on visualforce page for the custom object records. I use Javascript Remoting method to get data from the controller and then on basis of the records I create addresses.

Once the data is populated, I use the google maps api to get the lat/lng to show markers, and then show related record data on the Infowindow. However, at the time I load my record page just few markers are shown (12 out of 300 records).

Visualforce Page:

```
  <apex:page Controller="DoorKnockingController">

  <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 50% }
       body { height: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map-canvas { height: 50% }
     </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=""></script>
  <script>
   var map;

    Visualforce.remoting.timeout = 120000;

     var recordid='{!$currentPage.parameters.id}';

 function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.762324 , -122.163301),
    zoom: 12
    };
   loadHotels();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

 }

 function loadHotels() {

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = "";
  var latitude , longitude ,id , name , street;


 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.DoorKnockingController.getAddressList}',
        recordid, 
        function(result, event){

        console.log('no. of records : '+result.length);
            if (event.status) {               
            for (var i=0; i< result.length; i++) {
                 id = result[i].Id;
                 name = result[i].Name;
                 street = result[i].Address_Street__c;
                var city = result[i].City__c;
                var country = result[i].Country__c;
                var State = result[i].State__c;
                var postalCode = result[i].Post_Code__c;
                address = street +", "+ postalCode;  
                console.log(address);  
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

                if(results == null){

                addMarker(12345, null , 37.762324 , -122.163301);

                }else{

                  for(var i =0 ; i < results.length ; i++){

                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            latitude = results[i].geometry.location.lat();
                            longitude = results[i].geometry.location.lng();
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);                                                          
                            addMarker(12345, result[i].Address_Street__c , latitude , longitude);
                            } 
                           }
                         }
                        });               


                   }
                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                    event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
            }
        }, 
        { buffer: false, escape: true, timeout: 120000 }
    );

   }

  function addMarker(id, name, lat, lng) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat , lng),
        map: map,
        title: name
});

marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+          
        '<h5 id="name" class="firstHeading">Name</h5></br>'+
        '<h5 id="address" class="firstHeading">Address Street</h5></br>'+
        '<h5 id="city" class="firstHeading">City</h5></br>'+         
        '<select id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+
        '<option>&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;select an article&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;        </option></select></br>'+
        '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     </script>
  <style>
 #map-canvas {
   font-family: Arial;
    font-size:12px;
  line-height:normal !important;
   height:500px;
   background:transparent;
    }
 </style>
     </head>
 <body>
<div id="map-canvas"/>
   </body>

   </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, Google maps API restricts api invocations (for free account) to a defined limit per day / per server. Also, if there is a limit on no. of requests which can be sent in a short span of time.

A better approach will be to conert address to location (lat/ long) when the record is saved (using triggers). So, when your page loads, it can simply make use of the co-ordinates to display locations on google map.

Refer to Google Maps API FAQ to know more about these limits https://developers.google.com/maps/faq